# SQL queries to get (elo)rating history (for graph, highest points etc)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running a site with user ranking-list based on elo-rating.

I want to provide more statistics to users and I have pretty much covered, but cant really figure out how to make queries for these ones.

1. Players highest ranking points
2. Players ranking points history (for graph)

MySQL db has two tables for statistics: `ranking_statistics` which holds overall statistics:

```
id, ranking, wins, losses, draws, total6m, total8m, total10m
```

and `ranking_matches` which holds statistics for matches played:

```
id, home_id, away_id, home_ranking, away_ranking, home6m, away6m, home8m, away8m, home10m, away10m, datetime
```

Here is some sample data from ranking_matches:

```
46  442 456 30  -30 6   6   5   3   3   4   2013-10-14 21:22:58
54  456 480 34.0391 -34.0391    6   4   6   4   2   1   2013-10-16 17:33:37
55  473 475 30  -30 9   9   7   8   6   4   2013-10-17 03:06:41
```

and from ranking_statistics:

```
442 1029.97 7   2   6   120 89  55
456 1003.93 6   2   5   99  84  65
```

I would want to retrieve players highest ranking points on history (ranking_statistics.ranking holds current points) and that could be retrieved from ranking_matches by quering all matches with players id as home or away and then calculating all ranking changes with highest score remembered (starting points is 1000). With this query, a graph of points history would be drawn also.

I have tried to understand how this is done but could not get it by myself and there doesnt seem to be any similar questions posted (or atleast I did not found any)

Results could be also calculated with PHP because all the data is output with it.

Sample output:

```
Player id: 442
Current rating: 1029.97
Highest rating: 1054.32 (on 10-23-2013)
```

For history graph, 2 values need to be retrieved to be able to draw a history line graph, date and rankingpoints.

Comment: Which database are you using?  (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, ...)

Comment: Then I'd calculate the maximum client side (in PHP or Ruby or whatever webpage scripting language you are using.)

Comment: I'm hosting with Joomla! so PHP would be a good option (all statistics is displayed with PHP)

Comment: You should post an example of how you want your output data to look like.

Comment: `Player id: 442
Current rating: 1029.97
Highest rating: 1054.32 (on 10-23-2013)`

Comment: Could not add image for linegraph, but there is 2 values that will be needed, datetime and rating (on that datetime).